# Excel Cannot Paste all copied cells

Tags: excel

So I have around 16.000 cells to copy from one column to another one. If I copy paste it, only the first 1000 cells get pasted, the lower i get in the sheet, the less cells get pasted.

I cannot move & replace the column itself aswell since I m getting the error "This can`tbe done on a multiple range selection".

How can I copy all the cells at once? Thanks in advance

Comment: Even worse, I just noticed that excel merges cells, so the paste outcome is wrong all in all

Comment: A data example would help. To copy, just make sure you select those 16.000 cells and nothing else. Are there any merged cells in those 16.000? Are those cells formulas or values?

Comment: I wrote a vba with a do loop now, gonna post it as soon as the query is over.

Comment: Have you a filter in place?  If so that can give weird results.

Answer (score 0):

So i solved it over a looped vba:

````
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+ü
'

For i = 1 To 36430

    Range("L" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Next i
   
End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would use a loop here so maybe I'm missing something. Additionally When moving data in vba it's faster to move arrays than to copy/paste the data. e.g. something like this should be faster:

```
Sub CopySelection()
Dim addr As String, ArrToCopy, TargetCell As String, Rw As Long, Cl As Long
addr = selection.Areas(1).Address(False, False)
ArrToCopy = Sheet1.Range(addr).Value2
TargetCell = InputBox("What is the target StartCell?") 'e.g. B5
Cl = Range(TargetCell).Column
Rw = Range(TargetCell).Row
With Sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(Rw, Cl), .Cells(Rw - 1 + UBound(ArrToCopy, 1), Cl - 1 + UBound(ArrToCopy, 2))).Value2 = ArrToCopy
End With
End Sub
```

hope this helps.